# Can't set cookie in Chrome Dev tools on localhost

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, localhost, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to set (change) cookie in Chrome Dev tool, but it only stores the name, not the value.

Steps:

1. open page at `localhost:3000`
2. open dev tools
3. add new cookie
4. set name
5. set value
6. refresh page

Actual result: the cookie with its name is there, but value is empty.

Funny part - this was working a couple of days ago, can't think of what has changed since then.

OS - MacOS v. 10.14.3
Chrome - v. 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Also I noticed the cookie is highlighted in red color (see MyCookie on the screenshot).

[image: not being able to set cookie in dev tools]

Setting cookie for this page works just fine in Firefox.

Already tried:

1. open page from `127.0.0.1:3000` instead of `localhost`
2. restart chrome
3. restart OS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turned out I have to set an expiration date for MyCookie (all this in DevTools). However, this is confusing because:

1. I'm pretty much sure it worked without an expiation date before.
2. i18next cookie has no expiration date and sits there just fine.

Answer (score 9):

opened chrome://flags and set the value of "Partitioned Cookies" to Enabled" and relaunched the browser. After that the red row did not appear and I am able to set the cookies like before.

Comment: **This** is the way.

Answer (score 8):

With the new versin of chrome Max-age of cooke can set in following way using 
dev tools -> console set document.cookie manually.
document.cookie='token=1234'.
We will get following things
Cookie Name: token
Cookie Value: 1234
Expires / Max-Age: 2019-12-26T15:22:22.000Z